# Why celery logs all to terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I al trying to make Celery logging to file. 
My log_config.yaml is:

```
version: 1

formatters:
  default:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'

loggers:

  sqlalchemy:
    level: CRITICAL
    handlers: [debug_handler]

  pepko.app:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [debug_handler]

  celery:
    handlers: [debug_handler]
    level: DEBUG


handlers:
  debug_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    formatter: default
    filename: pepkologs.log
    backupCount: 2
    level: DEBUG

root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [debug_handler]
```

and I have

```
flask_app.config['CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER'] = True
```

But celery is still writing

```
[2017-09-22 11:45:08,800: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Beat
[2017-09-22 11:45:08,802: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2017-09-22 11:45:08,805: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[2017-09-22 11:45:08,808: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
```

and another ALL stuff to terminal. What I am doing wrong?